# Word use in Motorsport Context

Tags: context

I'm trying to design some t-shirts for a local Porsche Workshop in Australia and I'm wanting to use the german words for 'Power & Performance'. The context being powerful sports cars.

I've been offered two options and wondering which is more correct.

Thanks!

'Stärke & Leistung'   or    'Kraft & Leistung'

Comment: It is being used in an English speaking country so it will lose the tie to German if we utilise the English works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your translations are correct.

But: The resulting slogans sound pretty lame in German (Maybe, because "Leistung" and "Kraft" are near-synonyms in colloquial German). You would be looking for a bit more *density* in German, like using a preposition or putting some more "message" into it.

Maybe by translating Newton's second law to German?

> Beschleunigung = Masse / Kraft

Or, even better (P = F × v)

> Leistung = Kraft × Geschwindigkeit

Comment: *Beschleunigung = Masse x Kraft* ist aber falsch, es muss heißen *Kraft = Masse x Beschleunigung* - und streng genommen gilt das auch nur für Spezialfall einer konstanten Masse (der im Motorsport aufgrund von Kraftstoffverbrauch nicht wirklich gegeben ist), allgemeingültig ist Kraft = zeitliche Änderung des Impulses ('tschulligung für's Klugscheißen ;-) )

Comment: 1. Teil: Klar. Man sollte nochmal lesen, was man schreibt. 2. Teil: Na -ja. Das passt nicht so richtig auf ein T-Shirt...

Comment: ooch - *F = p* mit noch nem Punkt über dem p könnte man sogar in riesig großen Buchstaben drauf drucken ;-) Dann verstehen's zwar nur noch Nerds - aber irgendwas is ja immer...

Comment: Richtig ist `Beschleunigung = Kraft / Masse`. Sonst wäre die Beschleunigung ja größer, wenn die Kraft kleiner ist.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably more of a creative question than a language one, and tofro made some very nice suggestions.

To add something about your specific question, "Stärke" and "Kraft" can both mean "power", but they have different nuances. "Stärke" can also refer to "strength", "fortitude" and the like. It doesn't have to be *physical* power.

"Kraft" on the other hand typically focusses on physical strength. It can also have negative connotations like in "viel Kraft, wenig Hirn" (roughly translates to "muscles all over, but empty in the brain").

If you want to go with the German translation of "Power & Performance", I'd say it's a matter of what you want to emphasize - the sheer horse powers of the cars or their overall "strength".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - probably more the horsepower angle :)

Answer (score 0):

> Drehmoment
>
> mal Drehzahl
>
> heißt **Leistung**

Engine related tech talk is always about *Drehmoment* and *Drehzahl* in German and *Leistung* doesn't just mean *power* but also *achievement* in German so you want to use that one in any case.

You also want to use the verb *heißen* as it means both *is called* and *to greet*.